# how to solve Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found?

Tags: flex3, elips-studio

I have created application, it showing this error message during initialization (Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.),how to fix it?
thank's in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I cannot provide a definitive answer - but it's more than likely the path for some resources needed for your Flex application are incorrect. Can you provide any more details? Double check all of your paths.